# Will the Unity launcher ever be animated?

Tags: 11.10, unity

Moving my mouse over the Unity launcher feels like I'm moving my mouse over the desktop wallpaper. Lifeless. Will the developers ever consider animating the launcher so that the mouse experience is a bit enhanced? I'm not here to give ideas, but even if the icons increased in size on a mouse-over event, would be a better than nothing. Or changed colour. Or something.

It's the attention to detail that puts Apple in the forefront of aesthetics. I'd like Ubuntu to be at the forefront and, while I'm thrilled at where it's headed, something as rudimentary as touch-and-feel should be included in the interface.

Comment: not for 11.10 as you have tagged - have you posed this on the developers mailing list? http://unity.ubuntu.com/contact-us/

Comment: +1 for the idea, consider putting this on Ubuntu Brainstorm

Comment: I am not on the developers mailing list, but anyone else is welcome to post it to them. It's an open source idea!

Comment: it's a great idea! **But** you cannot answer this today right now! since a question stating **will** cannot ever be answered since we doesn't know what the future will bring.